# unable to find element on closed window - IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I'm clicking on a link()in my web, it opens another window. 
Problem is that I made it few seconds before and all is ok. but when opening this pop up it says: "nosuchwindowexception unable to find element on closed window"
it happens on  IE9.
I have tried everything I found about protection mode in IE(all options are enabled and I even tried all options as disabled) , and disable UAC. in addition , I have tried driver.Switch()... and windows handling... I even tried waiting method.
I'm sure I'll get the solution here by experts.
Thanks in advance
Yaniv.

Edit to include code in comment:

```
public void CreateNewApplicationForustomer() {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    webdriver.SwitchTo().Window("6c4d49a14b74e21187f5441ea175347c");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    CreateApplicationButton.Click();
    _webdriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    string a = _webdriver.CurrentWindowHandle.ToString();
    // _webdriver.SwitchTo().Frame("someframe");
    // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    // Subject.SendKeys("automation");
}
```

Comment: Can you attach some code?

Comment: Thanks @Locke125
public void CreateNewApplicationForustomer()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            _webdriver.SwitchTo().Window("6c4d49a14b74e21187f5441ea175347c");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            CreateApplicationButton.Click();
            _webdriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
            string a = _webdriver.CurrentWindowHandle.ToString();
            
           // _webdriver.SwitchTo().Frame("someframe");
           // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
       //     Subject.SendKeys("automation");

            
        }